# Hosting multiple websites using MAMP without exposing sensitive files?

Tags: web-hosting, apache

So here's the thing, I've created 3 projects which I would like to somehow host simultaneously so that each of them can be viewed at any time. Currently, I am hosting them myself using MAMP, however, I have done so by doing this:

- I've placed all projects in htdocs folder
- I've set htdocs as the document root C:\MAMP\htdocs

This means that when I access my IP, I'm presented with a list of the folders of all projects and in order to actually open the website, I have to navigate to the public folder where the index is located of each project. This means that all the projects can be viewed if the user navigates to the public folder, however, it also means that all the folders and files which are not meant to be public, are in fact public and visible.

This means that when I go to:

- http://99.999.99.999 - I see all projects and their directories
- http://99.999.99.999/Project1/ - I see all the project files and
  folders which are outside of the public folder so that they're
  protected. This is a huge no-no for me because I'm using an API key which is stored inside an .env file inside this folder, so I can't have it public
- http://99.999.99.999/Project1/public - Display the index of the
  project

Obviously I could just set the document root to be

C:\MAMP\htdocs\Project1\public
But then I'll only be showcasing 1 project. As you can see, using my methods I could either showcase 1 project at a time only, or have the ability to showcase all of them at the cost of exposing all files and folders which shouldn't be exposed which is less than ideal.

So I was wondering if there's a way to make it so that when a user goes to http://99.999.99.999/1 ( the IP is just an example ), the first project appears ( meaning the document root is the public folder of the first project ) and if the user goes to http://99.999.99.999/2, the second project appears ( meaning the document root is the public folder of the second project ).

Any alternatives are welcome.

Comment: I don't quite understand. Have you set up MAMP in a way that your projects are externally accessible from the web or why is that a problem?

Aside from that, I use XAMPP and I simply give each website its own directory inside htdocs so that they are accessible via http://localhost/project1, http://localhost/project2, etc.

Comment: To do what you want, I personnaly use MAMP Pro. (ok, it's a paid version but it does the trick)

Comment: Hey @WSU Sorry for the late reply. The projects are projects are externally accessible from the web and I can access the different projects via localhost/project1, localhost/project2, however, this way I expose the entire project to the web, including env files that contain sensitive information. In order to host a project without exposing the sensitive files, I need to set up MAMP root folder to the public folder of the respective project - localhost/project1/public, however, obviously I can't simultaneously have several MAMP root folders for each project.